# Alternatives to ArcGIS' "RegionGroup" a raster

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7

I'm using the ArcGIS Python 2.7 interpreter in my PyCharm as I need several algorithms of the `ArcPy` package. However, I am having trouble with the `RegionGroup` of ArcGIS 10.7, as it sometimes crashes my loop with the `exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`.
I have already asked a question on how to fix that ([Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) from RegionGroup (ArcGIS 10.7)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/348276/145570)), but I am assuming that it is rather difficult to solve (at least Google seems to think so).
I need to stay with the 2.7 Python in my PyCharm, but maybe there are some alternatives to region group a raster?

Comment: When it is about raster data, I always think in GRASS GIS, which has powerfull tools for python scripts, but I am of little help beside this vague idea.

Comment: I also thought about GRASS, but wouldn't I have to use a different python interpreter for this than the ArcGIS one?

Comment: Good question. I have not worked with pygrass at all. Have you seen this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203310/connecting-python-script-external-to-grass-gis-7-program-in-windows-10? it might help you to answer the previous question

Comment: Maybe this is useful too: https://neteler.gitlab.io/grass-gis-analysis/05_grass_gis_python_session/